# Definition of a positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, positive-definite

In my notes for my Linear Algebra class I wrote the following:

> Matrix A is *positive definite* if $A=LU$ with positive pivots

where L and U are lower and Upper triangular matrices.

Now, it's unclear to me whether this means $A$ has positive pivots or $LU$ has positive pivots, and the textbook is equally ambiguous. All the definitions I found online use eigenvalues, which I have not learned about yet, or they talking about multiplying by certain vectors.

Can someone clarify the definition I wrote down?

Comment: It's unclear to me why it is that you consider those statements to be distinct. What's the difference, as you see it?

Comment: I like topics about positive definite matrices. So I googled your note at searchonmath.com/, and found this [StachExchange topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3665900/determining-whether-a-matrix-is-positive-definite-from-its-lu-decomposition) that might help this topic.

Comment: It could be that A has positive pivots but L and U don’t have them until you multiply them, or L and U each have them but when you multiply they go away, somehow. I’ll admit I didn’t know much about matrices at this point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are talking about the pivots (i.e. diagonal entries) of $U$ -- note that if you have $A$ in echelon form, its pivots may switch from positive to negative by simply rescaling the rows, so it's not meaningful to talk about the sign of the pivots of a general matrix. On the other hand, it is meaningful to talk about the sign of the diagonal elements of a matrix.

Every symmetric positive definite matrix $A$ has a Cholesky factorization, which basically states that it has an LU decomposition where $U=L^T$ and the diagonal entries (pivots of $U$) are positive.

Actually your starting point is rather interesting, because we usually define a (symmetric) positive definite matrix $A$ by saying that for every nonzero $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $x^T A  x > 0$. Then we prove things about it like the existence of the Cholesky factorization. Your definition seems to be for general (possibly nonsymmetric) matrices. You should nail down that ambiguity first.