# Determining whether a matrix is positive definite from its LU decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, lu-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

Given that $A=LU$ where $L$ and $U$ are (known) lower and upper triangular matrices, is there any simple way to determine whether $A$ is positive definite?

#### Background

I have been using [this algorithm on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#C_code_examples) to compute LU decompositions.

The comment section says:

> INPUT: A ... a square matrix having dimension N
>
> OUTPUT: Matrix A is changed, it contains a copy of both matrices L-E and U as A=(L-E)+U such that P*A=L*U.

I'm not sure what exactly 'E' refers to here, but I understand that 'L' refers to a lower triangular matrix, and 'U' to an upper triangular matrix, and I understand that the algorithm is letting these two cohabit the same square matrix.

I seek to determine whether the original matrix $A$ is positive definite. I have a feeling that $A$ is positive definite only if $A$ is symmetric and (after running the algorithm) all of the diagonal elements are positive. Is this correct? (Or is there some other way to determine whether $A$ is positive definite, from its LU decomposition?

#### Edit:

[Elsewhere on the same Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Symmetric_positive_definite_matrices) it says

> If $A$ is a symmetric ... positive definite matrix, we can arrange matters so that $U$ is the ... transpose of $L$. That is, we can write $A$ as
>
> $$A = L L^T$$
>
> This decomposition is called the Cholesky decomposition.

Moreover I have read somewhere that a matrix is positive definite if and only if its Cholesky decomposition exists. But I don't know how to put all this together (e.g. what "arrange matters" above means exactly) to determine from the LU decomposition whether the matrix is positive definite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can determine whether $A>0$ by examining the diagonals of $L$ and $U$.

$$A>0 \iff l_{i,i}u_{i,i}>0 \forall i$$

These products $l_{i,i}u_{i,i}$ are the diagonal elements of $D$ in the LDU decomposition, and $A>0\iff D>0$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3666909/86969).

(In the algorithm referenced from Wikipedia it is simply a matter of testing whether all diagonal elements in the output are positive.)

Answer (score 1):

We assume that $A\in M_n$ is a real matrix.

There are  $2$ definitions for $A>0$.

i)  $A$ is symmetric and, for every $x\not= 0$, $x^TAx>0$.

ii) For every $x\not= 0$, $x^TAx>0$.

Then ii) is equivalent to i) for the symmetric matrix $A+A^T$.

Thus we may assume that $A$ is symmetric.

Then the fastest method to see if $A>0$ is to use the standard algorithm that calculates the Choleski deomposition of $A$.

$\bullet$ if the algo. runs completely, then $A>0$.

$\bullet$ If the algo. stops with an error message, then $A$ is not $>0$.

Comment: Isn't there a way to go from LU factorization to Cholesky factorization (e.g. via LDU)? I don't know much about it, but it feels like they are tightly related and the conditions for positive definiteness should carry over.

Comment: No; moreover Choleski is slightly faster than LU and more stable (when $A$ is ill conditioned).

Comment: How about $A=LDU=(LD^{1/2})(D^{1/2}U)$ where $L$ and $U$ are unitriangular matrices and $D$ is a diagonal matrix? Isn't that the same result as Cholesky factorization (if $A$ is symmetric)?

Comment: Can you think of any counterexample to $A>0 \iff D>0$?

Comment: "NB. The LU algo. is useless" To the contrary, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3666909/86969

Comment: The LDU gives also the answer but i) its complexity is larger than that of choleski ii) You cannot obtain LDU from LU; you have to start all over. You really waste my time.

Comment: Not true. We can rescale the rows of U and (if necessary) the columns of L to normalize the pivots. $LU=(L_{new}D_L)(D_UU_{new})=L_{new}(D_LD_U)U_{new}=L_{new}D_{new}U_{new}$ then check $D>0$.

Comment: Or even easier: we can look directly in the LU decomposition whether the product of corresponding elements in $L$ and $U$'s diagonals are positive i.e. $l_{i,i}u_{i,i}>0$ for every $i$. What could be easier than that (if we already have the LU decomposition)?

Comment: Ah yes, about the condition $l_{i,i}u_{i,i}>0$, you are right; I forgot this property. I remove my NB.