# Is a symmetric matrix positive definite iff $D$ in its LDU decomposition is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite, lu-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

Given
$$A=LDU$$
 where

- $A$ is a real symmetric matrix
- $L$ is a lower [unitriangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Unitriangular_matrix) matrix
- $D$ is a diagonal matrix
- $U$ is an upper [unitriangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Unitriangular_matrix) matrix

can we say that
$$A>0 \iff D>0$$
?

### Edit:

My thinking is that $(LD^{1/2})(D^{1/2}U)$ is (probably?) the Cholesky decomposition, and $D^{1/2}$ exists iff $D>0$.

Comment: Oops sorry, missed the uni part. Will delete my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if $A = LDU$ is symmetric, we must have $U=L^T$ by uniqueness of the decomposition ($LDU = A=A^T = U^T D L^T$). so then $A=LDL^T$.

So if $D>0$ then by for all $x\neq 0$ denoting $y=L^Tx$ (why is $y \neq 0$?) yields
$$x^T A x = x^T L D L^T x = (L^T x)^T D L^T x = y^T D y > 0$$

And if $A>0$ then for all $x \neq 0 $ denoting $y = (L^T)^{-1}x $ yields
$$x^T D x = (L^T y)^T D (L^T y)=y^T LDL^T y = y^T A y > 0$$

Comment: Or you could invoke inertia since $U=L^T$.